# SQL Select Join the same table (sort by most replies)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I want to select * from "board_b" the thread that has the most replies. My problem is that the replies are actually in the same table. Take a look at this:

```
+---+-----------+---------+
|ID | name      | replyto |
+---+-----------+---------+
| 1 | newthread |         |
| 2 | reply     | 1       |
+---+-----------+---------+
```

*(NOTE: the name column is not set to those, it is just to demonstrate)* As you can see, `1` is a new thread, and `2` is a reply to `1`. Now I have a table full of these, and the table has more columns (text, timestamp, etc...) but the general idea is like the one above.

The thing I want to achieve is **select all threads, and sort them by most replies** (and also limit by 0, 20). I've tried looking in to joining tables but it get's too complicated for me to understand, so a sample code would be great.

Comment: Is this only nested one level or you can have reply to the reply?

Comment: group by replyto, count replyto and then join by id with the same table to get the rest of the columns. If there are nested replys, it would be better to add a column with the root thread id.

Comment: It's only nested one level @MilenPavlov

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
SELECT board.id, board.name, COUNT(reply.id)
FROM board_b board INNER JOIN board_b reply ON board.id = reply.replyto
GROUP BY board.id, board.name
ORDER BY COUNT(reply.id) desc
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: @Balut, need to add having clause to limit the rows as asked by the question

Comment: Do you mean INNER JOIN?

Comment: I tried `$db->query("SELECT board.id, board.textcontent, board.imageurl, board.nameyes, board.timestamp, board.tripcode, board.subject COUNT(reply.id)
FROM board_b board INNER JOIN board_b reply ON board.id = reply.replyto
GROUP BY board.id, board.name
ORDER BY COUNT(reply.id) desc");` but that only returned ´Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/haakonu97/public_html/postsreply.php on line 7´

Comment: Can you try to run this query directly in db? as it could be problem with PHP

Comment: Updated the answer with limit

Comment: @Bulat How would I go about getting the info out of it in PHP? My while() will only return this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/haakonu97/public_html/postsreply.php on line 8` I'm using `$id = $row['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `group by`:

```
select replyto as thread, count(*) as cnt
from board_b
group by replyto
order by cnt desc
limit 0, 20;
```

Comment: How do I select "name" (for example) in my PHP while afterwards? I currently do $row['name'] but that doesn't work with this.

Comment: Wait what? I have several columns in there, and I need to be able to echo them out in a while(), the $row is inside `while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){}` - This way, usually, I am able to go through each entry and echo the relative column values. I feel like I'm misunderstanding you and I apologise, SQL is not my strong side, neither is PHP for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.replyto, c.replycount
from
(
    select a.replyto as replyto, count(*) as replycount
    from board_b a
    inner join (
                select id, name, replyto
                from board_b
                where replyto is null
                ) b
        on b.id = a.replyto
    group by a.replyto
) c
where c.replycount between 0 and 20
order by c.replycount desc
```